# Oracle 12 - Blob in group-by column list breaks listagg?

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, listagg

We have a collection of tables from which we need a view created... there are 30-some columns in the view.  One (-the last-) column is using listagg to aggregate multiple values from one of the tables... another column is a BLOB from another table.

Everything was going well as I created the view one column at a time. adding the listagg--then began adding all the group-by columns.. when I added the BLOB column, error **inconsistent data type returned.. expecting - got BLOB**.

So, just a general question,... does having a BLOB column in the group-by list of columns for a listagg column break the whole thing? Is there a way to work around the issue using only SQL?

Any and all insights and suggestions appreciated.  Because there are multiple tables and many columns involved, I am hoping I explained the situation well enough to get suggestions without trying to build the entire case for review..

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your query?  Or at least a simplified version that has the same error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't group by LOB columns. If you're getting the listagg from one table and then wanting to select information from a second table, why not do the grouping first before doing the join?

Eg. something like:

```
select t1.col1, 
       t1.col2, 
       t1.grouped_col3,
       t2.blob_col
from   (select   col1,
                 col2,
                 listagg(col3, ',') within group (order by col4) grouped_col3
        from     first_table
        group by col1, col2) t1
       inner join t2 on (t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2);
```

Comment: and, if the blob column is in table 1?  is joining to the same table twice allowed here>?

Comment: can you join the same table within the inner query?